# Is substring or replace faster to remove the last character in a string?

Tags: java, string

I have lots of words that need processing and all of them end with `.`, 
Which option has the best time complexity?

1. `word.substring(0, word.length()-1)`
2. `word.replaceAll("\\."，"")`
3. `word.replace(".", "")`

Or, is there a better way?

Comment: Of the _three_, the first is fastest since it's O(1) (ignoring the copy characters which all these do). The others have to scan the full String.

Comment: Note that the second option will replace everything in the string because `replaceAll` takes a *regex* and `.` is the wildcard.

Comment: In that case you better use a `StringBuilder` or other text processing tools.

Comment: which version of Java are you using?  Older versions of java have different performance for `substring()`

Comment: You might want to see the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java) for the methods and decide yourself

Comment: oh, you are right, I am going to correct it.

Comment: you mean convert string into stringBuilder and delete? Is it a good idea, I am not sure about the complexity or how java convert string to stringBuilder.

Comment: in the substring way, we need to have word.length, does Java store it when we create a String or it scan to count it every time? If the it is the latter one, then it is also O(n) @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: It stores it indirectly through the backing character array. The source code is your friend.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A simple test (with JDK1.7.0_75) can show the difference:

```
private static final int LENGTH = 10000;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] strings = new String[LENGTH];
    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
        strings[i] = "abc" + i + ".";
    }
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        String word = strings[i];
        word = word.substring(0, word.length()-1);
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    
    System.out.println("substring: " + (end - start) + " millisec.");

    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        String word = strings[i];
        word = word.replaceAll(".", "");
    }
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    
    System.out.println("replaceAll: " + (end - start) + " millisec.");

    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        String word = strings[i];
        word = word.replace(".", "");
    }
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    
    System.out.println("replace: " + (end - start) + " millisec.");
    
}
```

Output:

> substring: 0 millisec.
>
> replaceAll: 78 millisec.
>
> replace: 16 millisec.

As expected, the `substring` is fastest because:

1. It avoids compiling a regular expression.
2. It is constant-time: creating a new `String` based on the specified begin and end indices.